# Cannot because "this.rabbit" is null

Tags: java, spring-boot

When I try to inject Spring configuration into my code, I get an error:
**this.rabbit null**
My service:

```
@Service
public class PaymentServiceImpl implements PaymentService {

    public PaymentServiceImpl(PaymentRepositoryImpl paymentRepository, RestTemplate restTemplate) {
        this.paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
        this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
//        this.rabbit = rabbit;
    }

    PaymentRepositoryImpl paymentRepository;
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Autowired
    private CryptoWalletsRabbit rabbit;

    private final String TRON_TRANSACTION_URL = "https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/" + rabbit.getTRON_WALLET() + "/transactions?only_to=true&limit=1";
    private final String TRON_ACC_URL = "https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/" + rabbit.getTRON_WALLET() + "/transactions?only_to=true&limit=1";
```

My CryptoWalletsRabbit:

```
@Configuration
@Data
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class CryptoWalletsRabbit {
    @Value("${ru.panic.lapayment.wallets.tron}")
    private String TRON_WALLET;
}
```

My **application.properties**

```
ru.panic.lapayment.wallets.tron=sa
```

Help me please, the error is very strange, everything should work. I tried to inject through the constructor earlier, but it doesn't work.

Comment: _"I tried to inject through the constructor earlier, but it doesn't work"_ well this does not work either as the instance is null - not injected with anything. Enable `debug=true` in your application.properties, restart and read the logs, it will describe how it injects what dependencies and why.

Comment: Try `@Component` rather than `@Configuration`

Comment: You can't do like this. You are initializing `TRON_TRANSACTION_URL` and `TRON_ACC_URL` before your rabbit initialized.

Answer (score -1):

You should initialize the fields that depend on `CryptoWalletsRabbit` inside the autowired constructor.

```java
private final PaymentRepositoryImpl paymentRepository;
private final RestTemplate restTemplate;
private final CryptoWalletsRabbit rabbit;
private final String TRON_TRANSACTION_URL;
private final String TRON_ACC_URL;
public PaymentServiceImpl(PaymentRepositoryImpl paymentRepository, RestTemplate restTemplate, CryptoWalletsRabbit rabbit) {
    this.paymentRepository = paymentRepository;
    this.restTemplate = restTemplate;
    this.rabbit = rabbit;
    this.TRON_TRANSACTION_URL = "https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/" + rabbit.getTRON_WALLET() + "/transactions?only_to=true&limit=1";
    this.TRON_ACC_URL = "https://api.trongrid.io/v1/accounts/" + rabbit.getTRON_WALLET() + "/transactions?only_to=true&limit=1";
}
```